# how to center the map on current user location (geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation, location, point

I have this code that I want to center on user location because now it centers it it under the coordinates that I have (above Copenhagen, Denmark) and it's fixed. I need to make my code to center the map on the user location and to show the points around it

```
function initialize() {

var locations = [
    ['kastelet', 55.6911, 12.5939],
    ['norebro', 55.6883, 12.5597],
    ['noreport', 55.6832, 12.5714],
    ['edisikvosi', 55.678272, 12.503643,],
    ['Sentosa', 55.713207, 12.526474,]
    ];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.6750, 12.5687),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}

// Check if user support geo-location
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var geolocpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: geolocpoint,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        }
        // Place a marker
        var geolocation = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: geolocpoint,
            map: map,
            title: 'Your geolocation',
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
        });
    });
}
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);​
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map.setCenter`.

```
 .....
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var geolocpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
          map.setCenter(geolocpoint );//line added for setting center
......
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer can u point me where to put it and what to delete from my code. sorry for being cheeky but i am in learning process now and i have bad understanding of the code :/

Comment: See the comment I  added only one line. other codes I copied from your code just to show position

Comment: hi i have new question it seems that i cant add more than 5 markers, when i add the sixth marker the code cant find my location any suggestions?